# How to consume an XML message from RabbitMQ in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq

My requirement is such that, i will be getting an application/xml message from rabbit mq, which has to be consumed by SpringBoot. I am able to get it as a string, but when I create an entity and try to get the xml as a java object, it throws the following error:

```
org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.exception.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener method could not be invoked with the incoming message
```

and followed by

```
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: Cannot convert from [[B] to [com.boot.RabbitListener.Model.XmlEntity] for GenericMessage [payload=byte[4], headers={amqp_receivedDeliveryMode=NON_PERSISTENT, amqp_receivedRoutingKey=jsa.queue1, amqp_deliveryTag=1, amqp_consumerQueue=jsa.queue1, amqp_redelivered=false, id=0afca290-7ee2-36f5-4297-afeacbc451da, amqp_consumerTag=amq.ctag-HZO32UVNiMf9hWo_pAr9Bw, contentType=application/xml, timestamp=1542820548981}]
```

I am new to SpringBoot and i read some articles in marshler, but i am not sure on how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Provide a `Jackson2XmlMessageConverter` as Bean in your configuration as stated in the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/current/reference/html/#jackson2xml):

```
@Bean
public Jackson2XmlMessageConverter xmlMessageConverter() {
    return new Jackson2XmlMessageConverter();
}
```